# glossaries: \printglossaries prints too wide

Tags: margins, glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package, and when I issue \printglossaries:

```
\printglossaries
\makeglossaries
```

the glossary is waaaaaay too wide:

[image: ttp://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rgdw.png]

My package options are

```
\usepackage[acronym,sort=def,
  style=long,
  nolist
]{glossaries}
```

Setting

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{4.65in}
```

right before the \printglossaries is promptly ignored, and I couldn't find any option in the glossaries documentation to influence the width.

When I use twoside as a scrreprt option, the effect is much more pronounced.

Any ideas why this might happen or how I would fix it?

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OPs answer moved from the question]

Just adjusting `\glsdescwidth` doesn't help, because you will have to readjust when your longest entry changes. So use a custom glossaries style instead:

```
\newlength{\glstargetwidth}%
\newlength{\glshspace}%

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
% put the glossary in the longtable environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
\setlength{\glstargetwidth}{0.29\textwidth}%
\setlength{\glshspace}{0.02\textwidth}%
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.69\textwidth}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{12pt}%
\begin{longtable}%
{p{\glstargetwidth} @{\hspace{\glshspace}}  p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
% have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% have nothing between glossary groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
% set how each entry should appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\raggedright\strong{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}% the entry name
##4% the symbol 
&##3,% the description
\space ##5% the number list 
\\
}%
% set how sub-entries appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}

\glossarystyle{mylong}
```

This will fix the width of your entry column, breaking the entry names when necesary.

Answer (score 2):

From the `glossaries` user guide (`texdoc glossaries-user.pdf`), p82:

> The tabular-like styles that allow multi-line descriptions and page
>   lists use the length `\glsdescwidth` to set the width of the description
>   column and the length `\glspagelistwidth` to set the width of the page
>   list column. These will need to be changed using `\setlength` if the
>   glossary is too wide.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was looking at that section specifically, but never saw that... PDF documentation for programming sucks.